# C15 Equivalent material in IS standard

Tags: mechanical-engineering, steel, standards

I am need to match [DIN C15 steel](https://www.matbase.com/material-categories/metals/ferrous-metals/steel/low-alloy/low-carbon/material-properties-c15-low-carbon-steel.html) with an Indian steel but I don't know the equivalent grade in the Indian standard. For example, DIN C40 steel is known as EN8 under the IS standard; similarly, what is the IS grade for C15 steel?

Answer (score 1):

C15 equivalent in IS standard is 15C4. You can check reference IS standards for 15C4 to confirm, or see [page 147 of Worldwide Guide to Equivalent Irons and Steels](https://books.google.com/books?id=SpcF9IrYKRoC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=15c4%20steel&source=bl&ots=CfBATl65Lg&sig=pQaQhKlEwJyQyxNZgswPcCA2jpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_8Mjsz5XRAhUW8mMKHSJCAN4Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=15c4%20steel&f=false).